# MySQL TRUNCATE & INSERT Long Runtime

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following process in my script. The method this is used in is rather lengthy but the majority of the time is spent right here. Im looking for a way to possibly increase its performance but not exactly sure how to accomplish that. Currently if there are ~700 items in `$list` the process can take upwards of 15 seconds. I would like to reduce that as much as possible. How might I begin going about that (within the scope of whats seen below)?

```
    try{
        $this->connect();
        $this->mysqli->begin_transaction();
        
        $sql = "TRUNCATE TABLE test_table";
        $this->query($sql);
        
        $sql = "INSERT INTO test_table (a, b, c, d) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
        foreach ($list as $item){
            $this->run($sql, [$item['a'],$item['b'],$item['c'],$item['d']]);
        }

        $this->mysqli->commit();
    } catch (exception $e){
        $this->mysqli->rollback();
        return $e;
    } finally {
        $this->close();
    }
```

One thought I had to somewhat reduce it was to make `$item` a non-associative array so that it would just be `...->run($sql, $item);` but I imagine the performance increase just from that would be near to negligible.

Edit: As to be expected, the main issue is with the inserts.

Comment: You can try and insert [in batches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526917/how-to-do-a-batch-insert-in-mysql) instead of inserting them one by one. You should also reuse the statement (not sure what `->run()` really does).

Comment: Have you seen my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63318861/1839439