# How to insert data in PHP MySQL form data which has multiple selects with multiple='multiple' enabled

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form with POST method with two select dropdown. In both select multiple selections can be made. Now I am using foreach loop insert data in MySQL. But it only works with single select dropdown not with 2nd select dropdown. I used `foreach(){ foreach(); }` loop with again it doesn't work. How to insert data with multiple select dropdown which has multiple='multiple' enabled.

This is my select dropdown in same FORM [image]

```
$cid = $row['cid'];
$work_location = $_POST['work_location'];
$interest = $_POST['interest'];

foreach ($work_location as $work) {
    foreach ($interest as $int) {
        $insert_oth_data = "INSERT INTO resume_spec_data(work_location,interest) 
        VALUES($work, $int)";
        mysqli_query($con, $insert_oth_data);
    }
}
```

Also, I don't want to use implode function as it will make data extraction difficult as table grows.
I want to store all select options in separate row of MySQL database.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/1839439) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Comment: What do you mean it only works with a single dropdown? What happens right now? Are you getting errors?

Comment: I am not getting any error just the data is not getting inserted into database. Working with single means if I use only one drop-down select not both. So I want a code to insert both select drop-down values when multiple is enabled

Comment: Do you have error reporting switched on? [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)

Comment: Yes, every error reporting is enabled. Previously when I was trying to insert data without foreach loop array to string conversion error was showing. Now after applying foreach no eror is showing but data is also not getting inserted

Comment: Then make sure that your `foreach` loops execute at least once. Are you sure there is data in these two arrays? `var_export($work_location)` and `var_export($interest)`

Comment: Yess when I select only one options from drop down ```array ( 0 => 'Andhra Pradesh', )array ( 0 => 'Software development', )``` this results are showing

Comment: Have you implemented prepared statements? Can you show the updated code. See my first comment, it looks like you haven't fixed the SQL injection yet.

Comment: When I select multiple options in both work_location and interest I am getting ```array ( 0 => 'Delhi', 1 => 'NCR', )array ( 0 => 'Software development', 1 => 'Web development', )```

Comment: Also I haven't applied prepared statement yet. First I want to build the logic to insert data correctly then I will rectify the sql injection code

Comment: That is the whole point. To insert data correctly you need to use prepared statements. Your current method with `mysqli_query` will not work! See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-statement

Comment: OK OK Can you please suggest me the code to insert data using foreach loop with prepared statement. I will try to implement it

Comment: For example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63318861/1839439

Comment: I tried to use your suggested code for prepared statement which is something like this
```$work_location = $_POST['work_location'];
 $interest = $_POST['interest'];

$mysqli->begin_transaction();


$insertStatement = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO resume_spec_data(work_location, interest) VALUES(?,?)');
$insertStatement->bind_param($work, $int);
foreach ($work_location as $work) {
    $insertStatement->execute();
}

foreach ($interest as $int) {
    $insertStatement->execute();
}


$mysqli->commit();```
but got error 
Notice
: Undefined variable: mysqli in

Comment: Please suggest me correct code

Answer (score -1):

Use a foreach loop per dropdown

```
foreach ($work_location as $value) {
    $value = $work; 
}
```

After this add the insert into your db.

Comment: I applied your method ```foreach ($work_location as $value) {
            $value = $work;
           }

           foreach ($interest as $value) {
            $value = $int;
           }
           
           $insert_oth_data = "INSERT INTO resume_spec_data(cid, work_location, interest) 
           VALUES($cid, $work, $int)";
           mysqli_query($con, $insert_oth_data);```


But I get error
Notice: Undefined variable: work in...
Notice: Undefined variable: int in....