# Store an array in multiple rows in MySQL

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I am just trying to store an array in multiple rows using MySQL Database. Unfortunately, it saves only the last value.

```
<?php    
session_start();
require_once "../phpquery/dbconnection.php";
    
$testings       = $_POST["testings"];
$presid         = $_POST["presid"];
$lab_status     = "0";
$patient_status = "1";
$update_status  = "0";
    
foreach( $testings as $testing) {
    
    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con,"INSERT INTO testing_schedule 
                                (p_id,pres_id,testing_perform,submit_date,
                                    lab_status,patient_status,update_status) 
                            VALUES ( ?,?, ?, ?, ?,?,?)")){
    
        $cur_date = date('Y-m-d');
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssssss",
                                    $_SESSION['p_id'],
                                    $presid , 
                                    $testing,
                                    $cur_date,
                                    $lab_status,
                                    $patient_status,
                                    $update_status);
    
        echo "Successfully saved";
    } else{
        echo "ERROR: Could not prepare query: $con. " . mysqli_error($con);
    }
}
?>
```

image of use with printr():
[image: image of use with printr()]

Comment: print `$testings` and see if its actually an array

Comment: sure. it is an `array`

Comment: While that is not coded in an optimal way, that code should create more than one row if `$testings` is an array with more than one occurance. So please check/prove that `$testings` is actually an array with more than one occurance

Comment: Having this line `echo "Successfully saved";` inside the foreach loop is misleading ay best

Comment: sure, I have already checked

Comment: Please show a `print_r()` to us. Add it to your question

Comment: I have added the image above. please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it this way:

• First, `prepare` the statement *once,* with `?` placeholders as you are now doing.  Separately prepare each statement that you will need.

• Now, before starting the loop, `BEGIN TRANSACTION`.

• Next, iterate through the loop, executing the prepared statement with the proper placeholder values each time.

• Finally, `COMMIT`.

• Now, use a `try{}` block to `catch` any errors that may occur during the loop.  If this occurs, `ROLLBACK` the transaction instead of committing it.

---

"SQL transactions," as illustrated here, make the entire update *atomic.*  No one will see the changes *while* you are in the process of making  them.  Instead, they will see the entire change happen "all at once" when you commit.  Whereas, if the transaction is instead rolled back, "nothing happened at all."  *(Plus, in most systems, transactions make these operations **considerably** more efficient ...)*

Comment: Can you please sketch the query may highly appreciated.

Comment: @MohamedNasik See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63318861/1839439